# Remove header and footer from Joomla 2.5 home page

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5 page consisting of a logo graphic and an entry button which I want to use as the home page. I've pretty much sorted out how to remove the menu module from this page but I want to remove the header and footer too but I can't see how. I would guess, perhaps wrongly, that changes need to be made in the template (beez20) index.php but what exactly? There seems to be plenty of advice online about removing either header/footer from all pages but not for a single page. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If header and footer are parts of design and not modules, you have to make an addition to template `index.php` to disable these parts.

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() != $menu->getDefault()) :
?>
    <p> This will be hidden from frontpage </p>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

You could check this tutorial to help you how to determine if user is viewing the front page for all joomla versions and the addition that is needed for multilingual sites: [How to determine if the user is viewing the front page](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page)